# Field extensions question and irreducibility

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Consider $\mathbb{Z}_2(\theta)$ , where $\theta^4+\theta+1=0$

Since $X^4+X+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]$,  we must therefore have $[\mathbb{Z}_2(\theta):\mathbb{Z}_2]=4$.

Hence, elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2(\theta)$ can be written uniquely as $c_0+c_1\theta+c_2\theta^2+c_3\theta^3$, where each $c_i\in \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Now I was wondering, since $\theta^{-1} \in \mathbb{Z}_2(\theta)$  ($\mathbb{Z}_2(\theta)$ is a field),

$\theta^{-1}=c_0+c_1\theta+c_2\theta^2+c_3\theta^3$

Using that $\theta\theta^{-1}=1$, and $\theta^4+\theta+1=0$, we get after quite a bit of algebra, that

$\theta^{-1}=-1-\theta^3$, right?

Comment: That looks right to me! Though notice over $\mathbb{Z}/2$ this is the same as $\theta^{-1} = 1 + \theta^3$ (since $1 = -1$) and this looks slightly cleaner

Comment: Yes, although there is a faster way to get that from the irreducible polynomial...  $1 = -\theta^4 -\theta$, so $\theta^{-1} = (-\theta^4 -\theta)\theta^{-1} = -\theta^3 - 1$.  Of course, these coefficients can be written more simply in this ring of coefficients.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Thanks!

Comment: @EricTowers Thanks!